# Simple video animation for teaching purpose

Tags: animation

I am teacher , I am teaching web technologies and programming languages ,sometimes i need explain some technologies by some animation .
here is an example https://vimeo.com/113530912

i wants know what techniques used in this like video and what best way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example given, [**motion graphics**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_graphics) techniques are used. Motion graphics consists of *Graphic Design* and *Animation*, of course. In order to create something like that, you need a tool which includes **typography, color and animation features**, but actually it's key to handle and process all of your **design assets**, like flow charts, icons, images or backdrops, which created in **other applications** with animation in mind.

**In general you can do this in many [2D animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_2D_animation_software) tools**, but In terms of flexibility and speed, I suggest you to use Adobe After Effects in combination with Illustrator or Photoshop. Almost every image and **vector format** is supported, so in this you don't have to deal with technical limitations. Also It's layer based and for this reason easy to learn for this kind of animation work.